# vba customize cells format

Tags: vba, excel, format, cells

I am needing to customize cells with simple thousands format, like `1000`, without any separator or decimal.

However, I wish to remove text fonts other than a number when they are input.

For example, I want to input `120118`, however in my paper from which I am copying that figures, it is formatted as a date, thereby `12/01/18`. I am needing Excel to  simply keep it as `120118` after typing, removing the slash (/). I have seen similar settings in access queries.

Comment: Sounds like you need codes for Worksheet_Change event targeting that column. Or if it's just for visual change, use custom NumberFormat `ddmmyy`

Comment: Sounds like you want these cells to have a `NumberFormat`. Select the cells, press Ctrl+1, go to the *Number* tab, and put in your format, e.g. `000000`. That said this question isn't a proper fit for this site (not sure why it's getting answers) - see [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply pasting only the cell value with:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Or just clear the cell format and format it again with your desired format.

Comment: hi, thanks for help. i need excel self convert the data on typing, in real time and not after running a macro; thereby changed afterward

Comment: hi, let me clarify:

Comment: hi, let me clarify: input data may concurrently vary from 4 digit number (thousand, ### without leading zero, i dont need) or a date (31/12/18, ddmmyy).   thereby if in range A1 i input 3112 as number, i want it to hold fomat number itself but if i input as 31/12/18 i need it to convert to thousands number format returning 3112, same as earlier input. i tried 
   [>40000]gmm;#####     because date number expression are always over than 40000. however in case of date input it holds date format instead convert. any idea? thanks

Comment: I dont have an answer right now using formatting but with vba or Excel worksheet functions you can accomplish what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. Selecting the range
2. Home > Number > Number Format (or Ctrl+1 I think) > Custom
3. Enter ddmmyy
4. Okay

Can be done programmatically e.g.

```
Thisworkbook.worksheets("Sheet1").range("A1:A50").numberformat = "ddmmyy"
```

The above would only be a visual/cosmetic change and the internal value of each cell would still be a date (technically a number) for calculation purposes.

However, if I've misunderstood and you instead want to go from the date 21 Jan 2018 to the number 210118, I think you would need to get the range's value(s), format as DDMMYY string, then `clng()` - or maybe (DD*10000) + (MM*100) + (YY) might work, then format as "000000" to preserve leading zeros.

Comment: hello guys, i have solved out: 1) i customize cell settings as follow: [>40000] ddmm 2) then copy and pste xlValuesAndNumberFormats. thanks